# Partition function with Hamiltonian depending on parameter

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space, partition-function

Given a Hamiltonain $H(p,q)$, I know that the classical partition function for a single particle is given by an integral over the phase space
$$
Z_1 = \frac{1}{h^3} \int e^{-\beta H(p,q)} d^3pd^3q
$$
Suppose that the Hamiltonian also depends on some continuous parameter $\sigma\in \mathbb{R}$. I believe $Z_1$ would become
$$
Z_1 = \frac{1}{h^3} \int e^{-\beta H(p,q, \sigma)} d^3pd^3qd\sigma
$$
where the integration over $\sigma$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, in order to consider all the possible energies of the system. Is this correct? If so, why is $Z_1$ not an integral over the phase space anymore (but over a larger space including $\sigma$)? Isn't "an integral over phase space" its classical definition?